# What is the meaning of energy in the $y$-axis of the graph between 'energy' and reaction progress?

Tags: energy, physical-chemistry

I came across the following graph in my textbook. In the $y$-axis, they have written the energy of the reactants and products. But what energy is it? Kinetic energy? Potential energy? Is it the total energy? Please explain.

[image: Graph between energy and reaction progress]